# Using provider package, how to manage single bool for calling tow method in same page

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have login screen where there are 2 buttons.

> - Login
> - FB Login

I'm using Provider package to manage app state. Below is login bloc.

```
class LoginBloc with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isAPICalling = false;

  bool get isAPICalling => _isAPICalling;

  apiCallingStatus(bool isCall) {
    _isAPICalling = isCall;
    notifyListeners();
  }



  Future<LoginResponseModel> callLoginApi(LoginReqModel _loginReqModel) =>
      locator<LoginService>().login(_loginReqModel);

  Future<LoginResponseModel> callFBLoginApi(SocialUser _loginReqModel) =>
      locator<LoginService>().fbLogin(_loginReqModel);

}
```

I'm using **isAPICalling** to manage loader in the Login screen.

Below are two button's code simple login and fb login.

```
Widget _loginBtn(LoginBloc _bloc) {
    return RoundButtonWidget(
      label: Translations.of(context).text('login'),
      isAPICalling: _bloc.isAPICalling,
      buttonTap: () {
        Utils.hideKeyboard(context);
        _globalFormKey.currentState.save();

        if (_checkValidation()) {          
          _bloc.apiCallingStatus(true);
          _bloc.callLoginApi(_loginReqModel).then((result) async {
            _bloc.apiCallingStatus(false);
            if (result.success == 1) {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
            } else {
              Utils.openAlertDialog(result.message, context);
            }
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

   Widget _facebookBtn(LoginBloc _bloc) {
        return RoundButtonWidget(
          label: Translations.of(context).text('login'),
          isAPICalling: _bloc.isAPICalling,
          buttonTap: () {
            Utils.hideKeyboard(context);
            _globalFormKey.currentState.save();

            if (_checkValidation()) {          
              _bloc.apiCallingStatus(true);
              _bloc.callFBLoginApi(_loginReqModel).then((result) async {
                _bloc.apiCallingStatus(false);
                if (result.success == 1) {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
                } else {
                  Utils.openAlertDialog(result.message, context);
                }
              });
            }
          },
        );
      }
```

Here issue is, When I click on any of the button then both's buttons loader will display. How can I manage state so loader will display only for clickable button?

Comment: with a single bool, that's not working.. it will works with a single String maybe something like thisr eturn RoundButtonWidget(
          label: Translations.of(context).text('login'),
          isAPICalling: _bloc.isAPICalling == 'FB',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not achieve it by using single `bool`. You can manage it by using `String` where for each button you can set **"FB"/"simple_login"**, Look at below

Here an Example with String `_bloc.isAPICalling == 'FB'`

```
Widget _facebookBtn(LoginBloc _bloc) {
        return RoundButtonWidget(
          label: Translations.of(context).text('login'),
          isAPICalling: _bloc.isAPICalling == 'FB',
          buttonTap: () {
            Utils.hideKeyboard(context);
            _globalFormKey.currentState.save();

            if (_checkValidation()) {          
              _bloc.apiCallingStatus(true);
              _bloc.callFBLoginApi(_loginReqModel).then((result) async {
                _bloc.apiCallingStatus(false);
                if (result.success == 1) {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
                } else {
                  Utils.openAlertDialog(result.message, context);
                }
              });
            }
          },
        );
      }
```